# What is track context of a changelist in PyCharm 2018.02

Tags: pycharm

## In brief

Recently we have "track context" checkbox for changelist, what are they?

## In Details

As the snapshots below, I notice we have "track context" checkbox for changelist in PyCharm 2018.02 recently.

And with that checkbox on/off, my local changes behave differently ie. some time the changed file appears in multiple changelists, sometimes it remains in only 01 changelist.

So my question is what is that `track context`? I hope to understand its meaning so that to control the `git diff` among my changelist in PyCharm

p.s.

My [google search](https://www.google.com.vn/search?newwindow=1&ei=5dPWW4jNLNX7-QbK7bGYCQ&q=what%20is%20track%20context%20of%20a%20changelist%20in%20PyCharm%202018.02&oq=what%20is%20track%20context%20of%20a%20changelist%20in%20PyCharm%202018.02&gs_l=psy-ab.3...255076.257245.0.257372.8.8.0.0.0.0.132.746.0j6.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.0.0....0.V31u6AJN3v8) leads to [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-tasks-and-context.html) which guides us to some thing relates to [Task & Context in PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-tasks-and-context.html), though I'm a bit lost there.

Snapshot 01

[image]

Snapshot 02

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Track context" means that, when you switch the active changelist, PyCharm will switch your workspace (the set of open editor tabs, breakpoints etc.) This has nothing to do with whether a file can be in a single or in multiple changelists; that's a different feature (PyCharm can track multiple changed fragments in a file separately and allows you to put every fragment into a separate changelist).

To move a changed fragment to another changelist, click on the gutter mark for the change and select the changelist in the dropdown on the right hand side of the popup that appears.

[image]

Comment: So the current activated changelist will store the next changes to it right?

Comment: And can we move changed fragments around the changelist?

Comment: Would be lovely as you can share how to move change frangments around the changelist, thank you.

Comment: I've just try to 01 create new changelist and make it active, 02 make change to a file where I already have pending changes in another changelist - I had the new changes saved in the new changelist

Comment: Great thanks. This is awesone that be a game changer for my daily git commit